# Replacing text in Python

Tags: python, regex

I've been looking at the re documentation and at other questions but I keep running into trouble with regex.

I need to take what ever is in the [tag] off of the string.

```
string = "Article Name [Tag Name]"
#and I want to go to
string = "Article Name"
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not use regex so if that is a requirement this is not an answer but you could do this:

```
 string = string.split('[')[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub("\s*\[.*?\]", "", string)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure [Tag Name] is always come after Article Name, you could do this without regex.

```
>>> string="Article Name [Tag Name]"
>>> string[:string.find(" [")]
'Article Name'
```

or with .partition

```
>>> string.partition(" [")[0]
'Article Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r"(.*) \[.*\]", r"\1", string)
```

This will only remove the tag if it's at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Even better without regex:

```
txt = "Article Name [Tag Name]"
if txt.rfind('[') and txt.rfind(']') > txt.rfind('['): txt = txt[:txt.rfind('[')]
if txt[-1] == ' ': txt = txt[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

here's one for multiple instances of [] tags

```
>>> string = "Article Name [Tag Name] blah blah [tag name2] blah blah [tag name3]"
>>> for i in string.split("]"):
...   print i[ : i.find("[") ]
...
Article Name
 blah blah
 blah blah
```